# checking if a method is defined on the class

Tags: ruby

How do I check if a method is defined on some class directly, not by inheritance or by inclusion/extension? I want something like 'foo?' in the following:

```
class A
   def a; end
end

module B
   def b; end
end

class C < A
   include B
   def c; end
end

C.foo?(:a) #=> false
C.foo?(:b) #=> false
C.foo?(:c) #=> true
```

Comment: Sometimes you want to just check if a method is defined in the current context without specifying a Class or Object. For that you can use `defined?( c ) #=> true`.

Comment: The title of this question is confusing. Sounds like it's asking for a way to determine class methods but it's actually looking for instance methods.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use this:

```
C.instance_methods(false).include?(:a)
C.instance_methods(false).include?(:b)
C.instance_methods(false).include?(:c)
```

The method `instance_methods` return an Array of methods that an instance of this class would have. Passing `false` as first parameter returns only methods of this class, not methods of super classes.

So `C.instance_methods(false)` returns the list of methods defined by `C`.

Then you just have to check if that method is in the returned Array (this is what the `include?` calls do).

[See docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000480)

Comment: This also gives true to all of the cases.

Comment: just updated the answer; you just have to set the first parameter of instance_methods to false to return only methods defined by C.

Comment: I got it. I knew that method but didn't know that it took such parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

For objects you can use [Object.respond_to?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001005).

> Returns true if obj responds to the given method.

For classes take a look at [Module.instance_methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000480)

> Returns an array containing the names of the public and protected instance methods in the receiver.

Comment: It gives true to all of the cases C.new.foo?(:a), C.new.foo?(:b), C.new.foo?(:c)

Comment: Also note that classes *are* objects, so `respond_to?` works on them, too.

Comment: Side note: `respond_to?` will include anything defined by `method_missing`, whereas `#instance_methods` will not.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer to the question, but if you're reading this question, you might be interested in this, which uses `.instance_methods(false)`

```
class Object
  # This is more or less how Ruby does method lookup internally
  def who_responds_to?(method, klass_ancestors = nil)
    if klass_ancestors.nil?
      return who_responds_to?(method, self.class.ancestors)
    end

    if klass_ancestors.empty?
      return nil
    end

    if klass_ancestors[0].instance_methods(false).include?(method)
      return klass_ancestors[0]
    end

    klass_ancestors.shift

    who_responds_to?(method, klass_ancestors)
  end
end
```

For example

```
class Person
end

module Drummer
  def drum
  end
end

module Snowboarder
  def jump
  end
end

module Engineer
  def code
  end
end

class Bob < Person
  include Drummer
  include Snowboarder
  include Engineer

  def name
  end
end

puts "who responds to name"
puts bob.who_responds_to?(:name)
puts "\n"

puts "who responds to code"
puts bob.who_responds_to?(:code)
puts "\n"

puts "who responds to jump"
puts bob.who_responds_to?(:jump)
puts "\n"

puts "who responds to drum"
puts bob.who_responds_to?(:drum)
puts "\n"

puts "who responds to dance"
puts bob.who_responds_to?(:dance)
```

yields

```
who responds to name
Bob

who responds to code
Engineer

who responds to jump
Snowboarder

who responds to drum
Drummer

who responds to dance
[this line intentionally blank because return value is nil]
```